# After edit, post still not update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, hyperlink, routes

I just learning Ruby on rails for about 2 weeks, I'm beginner so it's so hard for me.

I created a blog which use created_at attribute to make link, example:

```
http://localhost:3000/posts/2014/01/07
```

My problem is when I try to edit post, I can edit but it not update.
I have a post "Hello", and when I edit it to "Hello world" it still is "Hello".

Here's my files:

routes.rb

```
get "posts/homepage"
root 'posts#homepage'
resources :posts
match 'posts/:year/:month/:day', to: 'posts#show', via: [:get, :patch]
```

posts_controller.rb

```
  def show
    @post = Post.find_by(params[:year], params[:month], params[:day])
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    if @post.update(post_params)
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

post.rb

```
  def to_param
    created_at.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
  end
```

Sorry because my bad English, It make me headache... I can't understand much about route

**This is app\views\posts_form.html.erb, I 'render' this form for actions new and edit:**

```
<%= form_for @post do |form| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id='error_explanation' %>
      <div class='alert alert-danger'><h3>エラーがあります、チェックしてください。</h3></div>
      <ul>
        <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p><%= form.text_area :text, cols: 75, rows: 15 %></p>
  <p>
    <%= link_to 'ホーム', root_path, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg', style: 'width: 100px' %>
    <%= link_to '日記一覧', posts_path, class: 'btn btn-info btn-lg', style: 'width: 100px' %>
    <%= form.submit :'登録する', class: 'btn btn-success btn-lg', style: 'width: 100px' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: what is `post_params`?

Comment: Sorry I forgot it, post_params is a method in posts_controller
`private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:text)
  end`

Comment: Try `@post.update_attributes(post_params)`

Comment: I tried and it still not working

Comment: I removed 'patch' and when I click submit button after edit, I got this error: `Routing Error
No route matches [PATCH] "/posts/2014/01/07"`

Comment: couldn't you just add a @post.save! to have it persist to the DB?

Comment: can you show us what your view looks like? it might be the case that there is a controller/view missmatch so your attributes are not saved propperly

Comment: what version of rail it is

Comment: your post_params seems suspiciousas they hold no value

Comment: @Enermis Ok I will, but how? Sorry I just create account 15 minutes ago, I searched my problem so much but I didn't find how to resolve this problem.

Comment: @NitinJ I use Rails 4.0.0

Comment: @NitinJ It worked when I use `http://localhost:3000/posts/1/edit`
But when I make link `http://localhost:3000/posts/2014/01/07/edit` it not working

Comment: You can just edit your question (at the bottom there are links to do so) and then just copy the content of your ../app/views/post.html.erb file

Comment: In rails 4 strong_parameters are used by default . so any time you try to update or create a model in controller by recieved params you have to permit that . take a look https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters

Comment: @NitinJ Thank you but I have permited that already

Comment: i need the logs when you send request to update action

Comment: @NitinJ  Thanks, I posted my log in answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen `update` method used in this context - it is a class method and requires an id as a first argument.

The standard way to do this is:

```
def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.assign_attributes(post_params)
  if @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

If this still doesn't work, check your `post_params` method - permit removes all the keys which are not listed in given list.

Comment: Thank you but it not working. I have tried it for 3 days.
If I use normal link `http://localhost:3000/posts/1/edit` that is ok, but when I change to `http://localhost:3000/posts/2014/01/07/edit`, it can edit but not update

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.update(post_params)
    if @post.save 
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined the post_params in your post_controller?

```
  private
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit! 
    end
```

(If this works you need to change the .permit! to a list of attributes)

Can you look at the console where you run the rails server and check if there is an error when you post?

Comment: Yes, I have. In the first time it worked for me, but since I have changed routes and insert this code into post.rb: `def to_param
    created_at.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
  end` it became not working

Comment: Can you get the rails server log from the console?

Comment: How can I get that?
Sorry I have just learnt RoR for 10 day, please teach me

Comment: Which OS are you using?...on mac to run the application I have to open a console and run the command rails server (now the rails server is up and I can access to the application via localhost:3000)....then in this console I have a log that updates for every action on the application.

Comment: Is that file development.log? I start server about 9 hours and now it's very big

Comment: Yes, but you can look just at the lines in the console, that are generate after you click on the link to update the values. You dont need the stuff that happend before. And yes is the file development.log

Comment: Thanks, I posted my log in answer.

Comment: Ok. I need to comment here :)...how are you calling the function to_param? In after update? (in your model)

Comment: ok, my bad. to_param is already called automatically. Have you tried to change in your controller the first line of the update from `@post = Post.find(params[:id]) to @post = Post.find_by(params[:year], params[:month], params[:day])` ?

Comment: I tried it but it not working, this is my erb template:
`<%= link_to '編集', edit_post_path(@post.id), ....etc...`
I really got stressout with this problem :(
I can't understand much about routing of RoR :(

Comment: If you look at your .log you are not posting the id `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"YI0eU6yGGHsUT5Ymxf0AkJTQnMot3GcmODJq4WsXKdo=", "post"=>{"text"=>"こんにちは。今日の天気は暑いです。"}, "commit"=>"登録する", "year"=>"2014", "month"=>"01", "day"=>"08"}`. Those are your parameters in the PATCH. So then you have a select where you are searching for the post with the id 2014. An I think this is why the post is not found. But in the update you are searching the post with the id parameter.

Comment: `@post = Post.find_by(params[:year], params[:month], params[:day])
    if @post.update(post_params)
      redirect_to @post
`
This is my update method.
Can you please tell me how can I fix it?

Comment: One more thing :). Can you run rake routes in the console and show the URI Pattern for the patch method of the post (the whole line)

Answer (score 0):

maybe your routes.rb is wrong, try this 
**patch 'post/update'** instead of **post 'post/update'**. 
This would be apply only if your form_for dont have a method options but if your form_for has a method e.g,

`form_for @article, url: {action: "update"}, method: "post" do |f|...`

then in your routes.rb, youre going to use this **post 'post/update'** instead of **patch 'post/update'**